# Deploy CakePHP application to webserver

Tags: php, cakephp, web-applications, webserver, cpanel

I am having trouble deploying my CakePHP application onto a shared web server. Here's what I've done:

1) I zipped the application from my local machine: `application.zip` 
2) I then uploaded the zip file on to my `public_html` on the server and extracted it

So now my application sits at `www.mydomain.com/application` which works fine, but once I move the contents of the `application` folder onto `public_html` (so that my application sits at `www.mydomain.com`) it doesn't load the application properly. It only loads SOME of the links of the home page and none of the styles.

So to sum it up.. the app works fine right after extracting to `public_html/application/`
But once I move the contents of the application folder to `public_html` it doesn't work.

How am I supposed to set up the folder structure so that my application sits at `www.mydomain.com`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Are you using Apache? And who's hosting your server? It's not 1and1, is it?

Comment: Yes it's Apache. And no I'm not using 1and1.

Comment: Hmm, all I can say is to make sure all the CakePHP .htaccess files are there (in the root of the application, in the app directory and in app/webroot)

Comment: most likely you haven't moved `public_html/application/.htaccess` to `public_html/.htaccess`. What you describe is mod rewrite not being enabled. It would be a better idea to put all your application files _out_ of the document root and make public_html a symlink to the `app/webroot` folder (or some similar permutation) - it's the only folder that should be in a web-accessible location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just happened to try deploying a Cake app in the same way to a shared server using CPanel and had exactly the same problem. What I discovered is that somehow (I think when I extracted the zip to the public_html directory there was an empty .htaccess file that didn't want to be replaced) the .htaccess file in the root of the application was empty.

Just make sure the .htaccess file in the root of your application (i.e. in public_html) contains this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Worked fine for me and I'm all set now!

Comment: Or (as indicated by my comment to the question) [use a production install](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#production) and make sure the document root points at the webroot folder. +1 anyway.

Comment: Noticed your comment, but as I'm using Cpanel I don't think this was possible, as it seems CPanel, and maybe other shared hosting, can't make use of DocumentRoot. For dedicated hosting though, yeah that would be the best way to go (and it's what I normally do - it's rare that I have to use a shared server, or Apache for that matter).

Comment: You don't need to be able to change the document root to have a production install; only be able to put your application files _outside_ the document root, and either link or copy the webroot to the document root (if it's copied, the [ROOT constant needs redefining](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/webroot/index.php#L34-L40)).

Comment: This seems to have solved my problem. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @AD7six I see. Didn't think of moving the webroot, not sure if linking it would be possible using shared hosting though. Maybe it's something to consider next time - I'm used to using Nginx with root access though, so usually it's more straightforward.

Comment: @kingLoosh no worries, lucky I'd seen your question yesterday so remembered to answer once I'd sorted it out myself!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try deleting cache files in app/tmp/cache
Not the folders but the files in the folders